# google cloud endpoints configure "service accounts" for Google OAuth 2.0 endpoint supports server-to-server interactions

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, service-accounts

I am implementing Cloud Endpoints with a Python app,  I need to expose the restAPI in a secure way https (this is authomatic),  The consumer of this Endpoint will be a java Application (not a web browser or app android or ios), and my questions is if there are any way to limit the consume od this Services only for that application.

I've seen  "Service Account" oauth but i don't know if i can use it for this problem and if is possible i don't know how to configure it.

Thanks a lot.